# SQL to Django ORM for group by with distinct

Tags: python, django, django-orm

What would be the django orm translation of the below query?

```
select date(start_date) as start, count(*) as tournament_count, count(distinct(user_id)) from tournament group by start
```

I think it should look something like

```
Tournament.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('start_date')).values('date').annotate(tournaments=Count('id')).order_by()
```

But this doesn't get me the `distinct` part of the original query

Comment: Django does have a [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct=True` in your `Count` function like this one.

```py
# your query 
tournaments=Count('id', distinct=True)
```

This is the SQL equivalent of ***COUNT(DISTINCT your_field )***.

For more detail have a look at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id9)